# BeautifulSoup can't access content of <text> tag

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, tags, html-parsing

I'm using BeautifulSoup (version 4.4) to preprocess a Wikipedia textdump from https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/ for further parsing.

The textdump document contains multiple articles, each contained in a `<page>` tag.

Unfortunately, something about the document structure seems incompatible with BeautifulSoup: Within each `<page>`, the text body of an article is contained in a `<text>` block:

```
<text xml:space="preserve">...</text>
```

Once I've selected a certain `<page>` block, I should be able to access the content of the text block as `page.text.string`.

In BeautifulSoup, `.text` used to be reserved for the content of a tag between its brackets. In more recent versions, `.string` is used for that.

Unfortunately, it seems like `page.text` is still interpreted the same as `page.string` for backwards compatibility. (Edit: `getattr(page, "text")` does the same.)

Is there any way I can get around this and access an HTML tag named `<text>`?

(Edit: For a syntax example, see https://pastebin.com/WQvJn0gf.)

Comment: Please provide the exact URL of the page you are trying to parse. The link you provided contains no `<text>` tags.

Comment: @DeepSpace Here's a syntax example: https://pastebin.com/WQvJn0gf

(I'm actually parsing https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-pages-articles1.xml-p10p30302.bz2, which is 595 (uncompressed) MB of text, so that's unsuitable.)

Comment: Does using `getattr(page, 'text')` do the trick?

Comment: @Chillie That has the same result as accessing .text directly - it returns the `.string` equivalent block with the content of `<page>`.

Comment: Which parser are you using?

Comment: @PaulaThomas LXML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `.find` and `.text` works as expected:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

string = '''<mediawiki xmlns="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/ http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10.xsd" version="0.10" xml:lang="en">
  <siteinfo>...</siteinfo>
  <page>
    <title>AccessibleComputing</title>
    <ns>0</ns>
    <id>10</id>
    <redirect title="Computer accessibility" />
    <revision>
      <id>854851586</id>
      <parentid>834079434</parentid>
      <timestamp>2018-08-14T06:47:24Z</timestamp>
      <contributor>
        <username>Godsy</username>
        <id>23257138</id>
      </contributor>
      <comment>remove from category for seeking instructions on rcats</comment>
      <model>wikitext</model>
      <format>text/x-wiki</format>
      <text xml:space="preserve">#REDIRECT [[Computer accessibility]]

{{R from move}}
{{R from CamelCase}}
{{R unprintworthy}}</text>
      <sha1>42l0cvblwtb4nnupxm6wo000d27t6kf</sha1>
    </revision>
  </page>
...
</mediawiki>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(string, 'html.parser')   
page_tag = soup.find('page')
text_tag = page_tag.find('text')
print(text_tag.text)
# #REDIRECT [[Computer accessibility]]

# {{R from move}}
# {{R from CamelCase}}
# {{R unprintworthy}}
```